# When do I start my plastering?

Tags: walls, plaster, construction

How many days after centering I can start plastering?

Centering is done on oct 1st. Can I do plastering to the outside wall within 14days from centering? Will it cause water leakage? Because we are not pouring the water to the roof. We are storing the water on top of it. So some of the water exhausts and some reaches ground through side walls?

Sorry for my terms.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Some Googling implies that "centering" is part of removing concrete forms from the hardened concrete, but as to the rest it isn't clear. Some more information, or perhaps a diagram, would really help.

Comment: Since it is structural I would guess it was a 5 bag mix (5 bags cement per yard) and it should be close. Years ago we would wait at least 2 weeks before coating and longer depending on the weather (if it was cold I think it needed to be above 50 deg F night time lowest temp).

Comment: @DanielGriscom I recently learned the civil engineering term is Shuttering and Deshuttering. So shall I start plastering to the outside wall before deshuttering?